# Java 3D Object Rendering with Yaw/Pitch/Roll

Tags: java, 3d

Im looking for a way of displaying a 3D Rectangle, which could be moved by the values a gyrosensor delivers from my arduino.

I just don't know where to start with the Implementation of the 3D Space, the communication works fine.

I did not find any useful information online, however, I just need a Window (Don't know, is JFrame enough for this) with a model that I can set x/y/z and yaw/pitch/roll etc.

Are there libraries or code-examples?

I did see one integration with JavaFX which I have never used yet, or the implementations were in other languages.

Comment: If you're okay with considering using C# instead, you may want to consider something like a [Arduino to Unity](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/10/07/how-to-integrate-arduino-with-unity/) connection since Unity, as a game engine, has a lot of these 3D modeling and control tools readily available. Just an idea to consider.

Comment: Yeah, I just know Java way better, except in these Graphics parts. However, I'll try Unity for now. I guess its more flexible overall.
Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unity worked out for this, even though i was getting buggy behaviour.
Therefore i tried out Processing, which turned out to work fine. There are some snippets online where you can pass in the values of your arduino and it just works out.

I cannot provide more details since the project was abandoned.